# SwiftUI: Update height of an existing row in list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm new to programming in SwiftUI. I created a list of a custom view that expands on tap. However, whenever I tap the custom view, the height of the list row doesn't update. Here's what my code looks like:

```
       List(){
            
             ForEach(ingredients){ ingredient in
                IngredientList(ingredient: ingredient)
            }
            
        }

        struct IngredientList: View {
           let ingredient: Ingredient
          @State private var showBody = true
          
          var body: some View {      
             Hstack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                   Text("Text 1")
                
                   if(showBody){
                       Divider()
                       Text("Text 2")
                           .font(.caption)
                    }
                 }
              }
               .contentShape(Rectangle())
               .onTapGesture {
                   showBody.toggle()
                }
             }
          }
```

I think it has something to do with state of the list but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: works with me!  You might have to move the IngredientList struct out of the list view.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is that it doesn't work when it's in edit mode

Comment: @Samuel, did you find any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Orange no I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I found an ugly but working solution. On the expanded item change, check whether it is a selection mode, remember the current data set, clear it, and set it back with DispatchQueue.main.async. It works on iOS 15.4.1. I hope Apple will fix the issue in the subsequent releases.</strike>

Update: try [introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect). You will be able to retrieve the underlying table view and call UITableView.reloadData() on the expanded row change